# Regex - exclude string starts with specific words

Tags: regex

I have a question for how I can build a regex rule to exclude lines include specific words.

For example, I have a list of links and I want to exclude lines include `example.com`

```
this line include link- example.com
this line include link- example.net
```

I create a rule to define a named group (link) but it reads all lines

```
.*link-(?<link>((?!example\.com).)*)
```

how I can exclude any line with work "example.com" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
^(?!.*example\.com).*$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `(?!.*example\.com)` - Negative lookahead to stop matching line with `example.com`
- `$` - End of string.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FtA3Qt/1/)

Comment: Should this one use with multi line flag?

Comment: @QuyTruong yes. you can see the demo by clicking on demo.

Comment: No need to use any flag if the regex is used in Ruby.